# Altering an element within a column (PySimpleGui)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'd like to update the image associated with a button inside of a column and have failed in my attempts. I know how to alter a button, but I don't see how to access the button element when its in a column.

Windows 10, pysimplegui 4.60.5, python 3.9.13

Normally, I'd update an image :

```
layout = [[
        sg.Button(key="-Toggle-", image_filename="my_image.png", border_width=0, pad=(0,0), enable_events=True),
        ],
    ]
window = sg.Window('My program', layout, size=(2700, 900), enable_close_attempted_event=True, resizable=True, finalize=True)
    
while 1:
    event, values = window.read()
    if <some event>:
        window['-Toggle-'].update(image_data=cf.encode_img_for_pysimplegui(fig))
```

However in this case, my button is inside a column.
calling: `window['column name']['-Toggle-'].update(args)` throws a `TypeError: 'Column' object is not subscriptable`.

How do I access an element inside of a column?

Comment: Same as `window['-Toggle-'].update(image_data=cf.encode_img_for_pysimplegui(fig))`, all elements are accessed with `window`, not with other element.